# React Flux store emit event not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

for some reason, EventEmitter's emit event not working.
`HomeStore.emit(CHANGE_EVENT)`
Is this because I use Coffeescript?

I tried to fetch 5 articles into an array as initialState.
and when the store emits change event, `_onChange` method in Component should call `HomeStore.newsLatest()` to update the list.

**Home.js.jsx.coffee**

```
  HomeActions = require "../actions/HomeActions.js.coffee"
  HomeStore = require "../stores/HomeStore.js.coffee"

  Latest = React.createClass {

    getInitialState: ->

      {
        list_latest: HomeActions.fetchLatest(1)
      }
    componentWillMount: ->
      HomeStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange)
    componentDidMount: ->

    componentWillUnmount: ->
      HomeStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange)
    _onChange: ->
      this.setState {list_latest: HomeStore.newsLatest()}
      console.log "update list_latest"
    render: ->
      `<article className="post-article article clearfix">
      <h2 className="title awesome">
          adfsda
      </h2>
      </article>
      `

  }
```

**HomeActions.js.coffee**

```
HomeDispatcher = require "../dispatchers/HomeDispatcher.js.coffee"
HomeConstants = require "../constants/HomeConstants.js.coffee"

HomeActions =
  fetchLatest: (page) ->
    HomeDispatcher.handleAction {
      actionType: HomeConstants.FETCH_LATEST,
      page: page
    }
  fetchPopular: ->
    HomeDispatcher.handleAction {
      actionType: HomeConstants.FETCH_POPULAR
    }
  fetchFacebook: ->
    HomeDispatcher.handleAction {
      actionType: HomeConstants.FETCH_FACEBOOK
    }

module.exports = HomeActions
```

**HomeStore.js.coffee**

```
HomeDispatcher = require('../dispatchers/HomeDispatcher.js.coffee')
HomeConstants = require('../constants/HomeConstants.js.coffee')
objectAssign = require('object-assign')
EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter
CHANGE_EVENT = 'change'

_newsLatest =

  list: []
  set: (data) ->
    console.log "set #{data}"
    @list = data

_newsPopular =
  list: []

_newsFacebook =
  list: []

HomeStore = objectAssign({}, EventEmitter.prototype,
  addChangeListener: (callback) ->
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback)
  removeChangeListener: (callback) ->
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback)
  newsLatest: ->
    _newsLatest.list
  setData: (d) ->
    _newsLatest.set d
  newsPopular: ->
    _newsPopular.list
  newsFacebook: ->
    _newsFacebook.list
)

HomeDispatcher.register (payload) ->
  action = payload.action
  switch action.actionType
    when HomeConstants.FETCH_LATEST
      console.log 'FETCH_LATEST'

      $.ajax
        url: HomeConstants.API_URL + action.page
        dataType: "json"
        method: "get"
        success: (res) ->
          HomeStore.setData res.articles

      HomeStore.emit(CHANGE_EVENT)
    when HomeConstants.FETCH_POPULAR
      console.log 'FETCH_POPULAR'
      return HomeStore.emit(CHANGE_EVENT)
    when HomeConstants.FETCH_FACEBOOK
      console.log 'FETCH_FACEBOOK'
      return HomeStore.emit(CHANGE_EVENT)
    else
      true

module.exports = HomeStore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're attaching your event listener at the right time.

```
componentWillMount: ->
  HomeStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange)
```

This tries to add a change listener to the component before the component is mounted. Try adding it to `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount: ->
  HomeStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange)
```

Edit (to reflect comments):

```
switch action.actionType
  when HomeConstants.FETCH_LATEST
    console.log 'FETCH_LATEST'

    $.ajax
      url: HomeConstants.API_URL + action.page
      dataType: "json"
      method: "get"
      success: (res) ->
        HomeStore.setData res.articles
        HomeStore.emit(CHANGE_EVENT)
    return
```

Comment: I actually put in 'componentDidMount' before, but it did not work :/ my require 'events' works correctly tho..

Comment: I think the issue is that you use an ajax request when you fetch latest. Because you emit the change outside of the ajax request, it actually triggers before the data is received. Check my answer for an update

Comment: You are right! I have never thought about that! It works, thank you!